# Incorrect JSON string

Tags: json

Is there someone who can correct my wnb JSON string? For some unknown reason, it doesn't work:

```
{"array":[{"a":[ "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element"]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}{"a":[]}]}
```

Chrome says: Unexpected token {

I was not able deduce the proper JSON syntax.

Comment: You have a lot of `}{` that should be `},{`

Comment: Site that can help: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Would it be ok if i leave the {} out and just do [],[]?

Comment: @SugarOnBacon i've corrected your issue in my answer .. just copy it and it should just work.

Comment: jsonlint.com ..... not teaches u about good json syntex...but u can edit online and check is json is valid or not...

Comment: Bookmarked it already :D thanks all.

Comment: Eda, may I ask why have you edited my question? I feel it kinda looks clumsy now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its missing several commas

```
{"array":[{"a":[ "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element", "element"]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]},{"a":[]}]}
```

the commas thats supposed to be within the first level of the nested array

Comment: After a few further errors with adding those commas to my php that creates that JSON i'm now shouting eureka!

Answer (score 0):

Your json should be like this given below and also you can test your json in [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
 {
"array": [
    {
        "a": [
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element",
            "element"
        ]
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    },
    {
        "a": []
    }
]
}
```

Comment: My JSON is sent from a php file with XMLHttp. :D Thanks anyway (learned how to make JSON look nicer)

Comment: just copy your json and paste it in jsonlint.com to verify whether it is valid or invalid